# Android app process permissions

Tags: android, process, permissions

Is it possible to build an android app that would require explicit user permission for each process everytime they start to run on the android device? Would it have to be a native app? What libraries would one need?

Comment: You'd need to be rooted, and probably a custom ROM.  I don't know about requiring it each time it starts the phone, but there are apps out there that allow you to turn on and off each permission for each app (although many apps would then crash without some of their permissions).

Comment: If you really mean an app that requires permission for each of its processes then you can simply implement it yourself - i.e. have each process ask for permission for anything it needs to do from the user when it starts and kill the process if the user says no. If you mean create an app so that all processes on all apps would require this then I think this would be a major task to implement and would need root as mentioned above. You also would need to decide exactly what you wanted to be your unit to restrict (e.g. process vs thread / light weight process etc)